# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript, typeerror, addeventlistener

```
document.querySelector('.number');
document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', function () {
  const guess = Number(document.querySelector('.guess').value);
  console.log(guess, typeof guess);

  if (!guess) {
    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'No Number!';
  }
});
```

I don't know what's wrong with the addEventListener, Can anyone please help me?Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are trying to access an element that is null. The dot operator throws an error when it's trying to access null.addeventlistener(...)

I am not sure if there is anything wrong with your HTML as its not been shared here. But my guess is it has to do with the HTML classes.

For debugging purposes print your document.querySelector('.check') and see what it consoles and based on that take it from there.